# A bug with Contribution Note in CiviCRM reports? Can I fix it?

Tags: civireport, contributions

When I try to create a Report with all contributions and include **Contribution Note** column (see picture), then the Report returns *only* those Contributions that contain Contribution Note. Or, conversely, the Report does not include contributions whose Contribution Note is empty/null.

In the Filters tab I leave the Contribution Note setting empty.

[image]

Furthermore, if I ask to return only contributions where Contribution Note is null, the Report does not return any (although many such contributions exist).

[image]

This way the Contribution Note settings works very different from Contribution Source setting. Namely, if Contribution Source column is checked, but there Contribution does not have any Contribution Source, the Contribution is still included in the Report.

What is the problem here? How can I include all contributions and display Contribution Note (if there is one) and not display Contribution Note (if it is empty)?

CiviCRM 5.68.1. for Drupal 7

Comment: How about using SearchKit rather than the report? Then this would be under your control